# wordpress white screen of death in amazon ec2

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, vps

install a new wordpress installation on an amazon ec2 instance
following the guide:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-with-lamp-on-ubuntu-16-04

my ec2 instance is a ubuntu 16.04
in the wp-config.php file enable the following lines:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );
```

also add the rules for the security group "http-anywhere" to be able to access by the ip address

when finishing the wordpress installation this works normal
and install the following (but not activated):

- learnpress
- woocommerce
- evolve theme
- ultimate member

and everything works normal

but when I turn off the instances via ssh or through the aws control panel
wordpress does not load and I only have a blank screen without any error

and I do not have any error in:

```
.../wp-content/debug.log
.../var/log/apache2/error.log
```

I'm going crazy with this problem

replicate the installation of wordpress in a virtual machine with the same plugins (without activating) in local and everything works normal so turn off or not the virtual machine

it's a wordpress error because if I can access

```
http://ip_ec2/phpmyadmin
```

normally

Answer (score 1):

Maybe when you stop and start the instance the ip changes. After boot Wordpress internal configuration is still referring to a different IP and hence is not finding CSS and other page components.

[Assign a static IP to instance](http://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/cloud/amazon/allocate-elastic-ip-and-associate-with-your-instance.htm) and change WP configuration files accordingly. Note that some configurations may need to be updated inside DB data too.